# Read N value of sheets in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I am trying to obtain a specific cell value through all the sheets. Where in the Excel file have four different sheets that have information that I do not need. (I can not remove those tabs, so I need to ignore those sheets.)

The name of each sheets will be different, do I need loop through all sheets, gather that cell value, and print it out.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('Documents/CA= 7/Request/ScriptTestFiles/TestSheet.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xl_file, 'Job 1')
#df.columns
df2 = pd.read_excel(xl_file, 'Job 3')
df3 = pd.read_excel(xl_file, 'Job 2')
#add a for loop that reads of the sheets and store them into a data set then print it off 

print('JOB\n')
print('PURGE,'+df.iloc[3][0])
print('PURGE,'+df2.iloc[3][0])
print('PURGE,'+df3.iloc[3][0])
```

Comment: What is the specific question here?

Comment: The specific question is how can loop through each sheet and gather a certain value and print out that value.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: The problem is that I need manual input the amount the number  of sheet. I want to have it have be able to read the X number of sheets. So if I get a sheet with 50 tabs, I can run this script and build all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas ExcelFile class can read the sheet names and output as a list you can loop.

[image]

Slicing the list of sheets or using Openpyxl to filter our list of worksheets.

[image: slice out hidden sheets]

Comment: is there a way to limit to the number of results. So that only 4- n-2 sheets I want to be print.  N= value the end of sheets, two hidden sheets are coming up. I do not want want those sheets to come.

Comment: Sure, you can slice the list xlsF.sheet_names[1:len(xlsF.sheet_names)-2] or use another library openpyxl that provides access to more excel features.